Does anyone know how I can keep my elements in the same position when zoomed in and out on a webpage?
Im pretty new to coding, and I was wondering if there is anything I can do in CSS, HTML, or JS that would stop my elements from moving around without using position: fixed; When I zoom out on a webpage or zoom in my elements such as images and paragraphs move everywhere and my nav bar doesn't expand to the size.
I've tried a couple of things like using a container and editing the padding and margin and looked into some media queries but im pretty new to coding and self-learning so im not sure where to look or what I need to research this.

You could maybe build a zooming function that is built into your webpage.
Here’s an example:


var zoomediv = document.getElementById('zoomediv')

var zoomin_button = document.querySelector('#zoomin')
zoomin_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '125%'
})

var zoomout_button = document.querySelector('#zoomout')
zoomout_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  zoomediv.style.zoom = '75%'
})
div {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0 3rem;
}
<div id="zoomediv">
  <h1>
    Title
  </h1>
  <p>
    this is a paragraph
  </p>
</div>

<button id="zoomin">
  <h1>
    +
  </h1>
</button>

<button id="zoomout">
  <h1>
    -
  </h1>
</button>




Thank you i'll give it a try! I would upvote but I dont have the rep yet sorry!
